# How to get a count from all table containing a specific column?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-content-manager

I have a IBM Content Manager with a DB2 database.

In ICMADMIN, I have a bunch of tables, and some of them contain a specific column (let's call it ID_CLIENT), which is an ID linking to one table (CLIENT).

**How can I get the number of rows for each CLIENT from every table containing the ID_CLIENT column?**

---

I know how to retrieve names of every table containing ID_CLIENT, but not how to join CLIENT on them dynamically.

```
select tabname from syscat.columns where colname='ID_CLIENT'
```

(let's call this query A)

So my pseudo query would look like:

```
select count(*) from CLIENT join (A) on CLIENT.ID_CLIENT = (A).ID_CLIENT
```

Comment: Hmm, one of the index-related ones _might_ have the info you need.  Otherwise, you're going to need to write dynamic SQL - one `LEFT JOIN` (subquery aggregate) or separate query for each FK table.  For a number of reasons (Especially security), you can't supply table names as parameters; you're going to have to construct the statement.

Comment: I don't think I can know beforehand the number of tables I'm going to have. I was hoping to be able to do this query by using some magic voodoo from icmstnlskeywords and such.

Comment: ...what is it you need this information for, then?

Comment: Well, all those tables contains documents. I'm trying to get the number of document for each client.

Comment: Shouldn't you usually _know_ what types of documents you're interested in?  How many tables do you have in that case, anyways?  I can't really think of a good reason for about 2 or 3 (that would reference the client id).  I'd imagine you'd get more false positives from tables that have the fk-reference, but _aren't_ document-related.

Comment: The database isn't mine, so I can't help the choices made.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to accomplish your goal by approaching it as a two-step process:

1. Query the SYSCAT views to generate a separate SQL statement for each potential child table of CLIENT
2. Capture and execute the SQL you generated

`WITH ctbls ( tbl ) AS (
SELECT RTRIM( c.tabschema ) || '.' || c.tabname
FROM syscat.columns c 
INNER JOIN syscat.tables t
    ON t.tabschema = c.tabschema AND t.tabname = c.tabname
WHERE c.colname = 'CLIENT_ID' 
AND c.tabname <> 'CLIENT'     -- we don't want to join CLIENT to itself
AND t.type = 'T'              -- if you want to work with tables only 
AND c.typename = 'INTEGER'    -- if you want only want CLIENT_ID columns of a certain type
)
-- Construct a left join between CLIENT and each table returned by the CTE above
SELECT 'SELECT ''' || tbl 
    || ''' AS childtablename, par.client_id, COUNT(*) AS childrows ' 
    || 'FROM client par LEFT OUTER JOIN ' || tbl || ' chd ' 
    || 'ON chd.client_id = par.client_id GROUP BY par.client_id;'
FROM ctbls
;`

Comment: Ah, so you CAN join dynamically on multiples tables thank to syscat.tables! Looks great, gonna try it and tell you how it went.

Comment: So basically, right now the only result I have is a one column (named 1) table containing the second part of the query for each table. Am I supposed to understand that I have to re-execute it myself, using a second query call?

Comment: Yes, as I stated at the beginning of my answer, it is a two-step process, and the SQL-generating query I provided is only the first step.